# How fast does the ESP32 take to service an interupt routine?

Tags: arduino, esp32

Good day, I am working with ESP32 on Arduino IDE. I have written basic external interrupt routine to trigger on a change edge. I then toggle my output "immediately" inside the interrupt.

I am currently measuring the input and output and I am quite surprised to find my toggled output being delayed by 38us on rising edges and 18us on falling edges. is there any way to decrease these time delays ? I have attached my scope images.[Rising Edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4KaD.jpg) [Falling Edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qikjh.jpg) [Signals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZUC5.jpg) D2 is my input and D1 is my output.

Can anyone explain to me the time it takes for the ESP32 to leave the main loop and service the interrupt?

In short I would my interrupt to be serviced in the in the shortest time possible as it stands it seems as though the delay is due to the time taken to leave the main loop and arrive at the interupt routine.

My code is as below:

```
volatile boolean toggle = false;
volatile int counter = 0;
portMUX_TYPE mux = portMUX_INITIALIZER_UNLOCKED;

void IRAM_ATTR Pin34RPM(){
  //xyz
  if(toggle){
  GPIO.out_w1ts = ((uint32_t)1 << 19);
  }
  else{
  GPIO.out_w1tc = ((uint32_t)1 << 19); 
  }
   toggle = !toggle;

}
  
void setup(){

  
  pinMode(19, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(19,LOW);
  pinMode(34, INPUT_PULLUP);//Crank
  attachInterrupt(34, Pin34RPM, CHANGE);
  
  
}

void loop() {

   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Apparently](https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=422) the expected interrupt latency is around 2 us; alternatively you can write your own [high level interrupt handlers](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/hlinterrupts.html) in assembler. If you're seeing significantly higher latencies, consider skipping Arduino - I'm not sure that the GPIO library there is oriented for performance. I'd start by dropping back to the Espressif's own [ESP IDF GPIO library](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/gpio.html).

Comment: Great you are using the right words which I did not know, I want to know if the latency can be reduced. Also are you suggesting that the latency I see is due to the actual writing of the pin (high or low). my feeling is that Im not getting the expected latency of  2us due to something else. Apart from switchin IDEs is there nothing that can be done to reduce it? this is part of a bigger code involving bluetooth, eeprom etc and im stilll a novice. reading those links are making me dizzy

Comment: Its almost as thought the ESP is intentionally not entering the interrupt immediately. 40us is not what I would expect on a 240mhz clock

Comment: The Arduino ESP32 libraries are built on top of the ESP IDF framework from Espressif. My hypothesis is that the Arduino implementation of either the GPIO or interrupt handling has poor performance, adding an order of magnitude of extra latency. To test this hypothesis, you'd have to write your interrupt handling and GPIO using the underlying ESP IDF framework, not Arduino. You don't have to switch anything. It's all down there, just read the relevant documentation (the API documentation reliably pops up when googling "esp idf interrupts" or "esp idf gpio")